# Powershell looping issue

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a unique folder name using powershell. This results in an infinite loop. The code inside the else part never executes which is trying to make the folder name unique.

```
$dirname = "\\" + $ServerName + "\d$\inetpub\Staging\Cms-" + $today.ToString("yyyyMMdd")

    $found = 0
$counter = 1
$newDirName = $dirname
Do
{   
   $LogMessage = "Checking directory: " + $newDirName
   write-host "##teamcity[message text='$LogMessage']"

    if(!(Test-Path $newDirName))
    {
        $dirname = $newDirName
        $found = 1
    }
    else
    {
        $newDirName = $dirname + "-v" + $counter
        $LogMessage = "Checking NEW directory: " + $newDirName
        write-host "##teamcity[message text='$LogMessage']"
        $counter++
    }
}
Until($found -lt 1)

MD $dirname | Out-Null
    $LogMessage = "Created directory: " + $dirname
    write-host "##teamcity[message text='$LogMessage']"
```

Where as the following works:

```
if(!(Test-Path $dirname))
    {
        MD $dirname | Out-Null
        $LogMessage = "Created directory: " + $dirname
        write-host "##teamcity[message text='$LogMessage']"

    }
    else
    {
        $dirname = $dirname + "v2"
        if(!(Test-Path $dirname))
        {
            MD $dirname | Out-Null
            $LogMessage = "Created directory: " + $dirname
            write-host "##teamcity[message text='$LogMessage']"
        }
        else
        {
            $LogMessage = "Unable to deploy, the directory: " + $ServerName + " is already in use."
            write-host "##teamcity[message text='$LogMessage']"
            exit 1
        }
    }
```

Do you see something that i may be doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you use the ISE and debug your script using breakpoints. The answer quickly becomes apparent. Your do while loop runs until $found is less than 1. But it is never set to anything other than 1 in the do loop, so it can never break out. I think this may do what you are looking for.

```
$dirname = "\\" + $ServerName + "\d$\inetpub\Staging\Cms-" + $today.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
$newDirName = $dirname
#Variable to hold a boolean for whether the directory was created or not
$dirCreated = $false
do{
    #If directory does not exist
    if(!(Test-Path $newDirName)){
        #create it
        md $newDirName | out-null
        #set variable that we are testing for to true
        $dirCreated = $true
    }
    else
    {
        #directory exists so adjust the name and try again
        $newDirName = $dirname + "-v" + $counter
        $counter++
    }
}
while(!$dirCreated)
#loops until a directory is created
```